# Chrome Extension, Security

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, google-chrome-extensions

I want to use this silly Bitmoji Chrome extension. However, Chrome warns that it can "read and alter data from any website."

So... even banking websites and others that use SSL?

Any way to restrict this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this would include banking websites and others that use SSL. There's no way for you to restrict this, though the developers could choose to do so.